# visual studio express hello word console application

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]I'm starting to learn C# and trying to create "hello word" application in visual studio express 2013. According to  [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx)  I should to do as below: "Expand Installed, expand Templates, expand Visual C#, and then choose Console Application.". However I do not see Console Application option. Any advise how to create new console project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image, you have visual studio express for web

you will need visual studio express for windows desktop for the console application template

[missing console app on visual studio question on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/843b16f5-77af-4977-9a0e-fc52234bc958/missing-console-app-after-rc2-on-vs2013?forum=vcgeneral)

[visual studio for desktop link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40787)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed VS C# 2013 express, then the only thing you have to do is to click on the white paper icon in the top left toolbar and to choose Console application in the Window that appears Make sure you have marked the visual c# applications Box to the left

Comment: Console application does not appear in this window. This is the problem.

Comment: could you provide a picture?